# Why Logcat does not print the message when startCommand() is called by the android system?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-service

I have written a simple code to check the use of service .

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d("msg","Service Started");

    if(intent == null)
    Log.w("msg","Service Intent NULL");

    g = (GlobalVar) getApplicationContext();

    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Job());
        thread.start();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("msg", ex.getMessage());
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

There are two buttons in my activity.
One button starts the service using **startService(Intent intent)** method and other one stops it using **stopService(Intent intent)** method.
1. I pressed the startButton and the msg **Service Started** is printed in Logcat. Intent will not be null this time.
2. Now , I go to Emulator's **Settings>Applications>Running Services** and locate my service and stop it. The msg **Service Stopped** is printed in the Logcat which I have written in the **onDestroy()** method of the service.

### Here is the part which I don't understand.

*The Android System restarts the service itself after some seconds and this time the msg **Service Started** is not printed. The documentation states that intent will be null. BUT the msg **Service Intent NULL** is also not printed.*

### How do I know that android system restarts the service?

I have printed some messages in the Thread that my service starts . Those msgs start printing automatically in the logcat after few seconds of stopping the service from the emulator settings.

Any ideas why those LogCat messages are NOT being printed ?

Answer (score 0):

What i guess that you should have some basic understanding of these thins give below....

Log.e: This is for when bad stuff happens. Use this tag in places like inside a catch statment. You know and error has occurred and therefore you're logging an error.

Log.w: Use this when you suspect something shady is going on. You may not be completely in full on error mode, but maybe you recovered from some unexpected behavior. Basically, use this to log stuff you didn't expect to happen but isn't necessarily an error. Kind of like a "hey, this happened, and it's weird, we should look into it."

Log.i: Use this to post useful information to the log. For example: that you have successfully connected to a server. Basically use it to report successes.

Log.d: Use this for debugging purposes. If you want to print out a bunch of messages so you can log the exact flow of your program, use this. If you want to keep a log of variable values, use this.

Log.v: Use this when you want to go absolutely nuts with your logging. If for some reason you've decided to log every little thing in a particular part of your app, use the Log.v tag.
and refer this also [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

i'm sure this will help you out...Thanks...

Comment: This is not what I was looking for but still it is valuable information .Thanks